# Create new data structure by combining list and dict

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have two objects, the first, `items`, which is a list of a lists where each list counts the frequency of a term in a document

```
[('lorem', 1), ('ipsum', 1), ('dolor', 1), ('sit', 1), ('amet', 1)]
[('consectetur', 1), ('adipiscing', 1), ('elit', 1), ('sed', 1), ('eiusmod', 1), ('tempor', 1), ('incididunt', 1), ('ut', 3), ('labore', 1), ('et', 1), ('dolore', 1), ('magna', 1), ('aliqua', 1), ('enim', 1), ('ad', 1), ('minim', 1), ('veniam', 1), ('quis', 1), ('nostrud', 1), ('exercitation', 1), ('ullamco', 1), ('laboris', 1), ('nisi', 1), ('aliquip', 1), ('ex', 1), ('ea', 1), ('commodo', 1), ('consequat', 1)]
[('duis', 1), ('aute', 1), ('irure', 1), ('dolor', 1), ('reprehenderit', 1), ('voluptate', 1), ('velit', 1), ('esse', 1), ('cillum', 1), ('dolore', 1), ('eu', 1), ('fugiat', 1), ('nulla', 1), ('pariatur', 1)]
[('excepteur', 1), ('sint', 1), ('occaecat', 1), ('cupidatat', 1), ('non', 1), ('proident', 1), ('sunt', 1), ('culpa', 1), ('qui', 1), ('officia', 1), ('deserunt', 1), ('mollit', 1), ('anim', 1), ('id', 1), ('est', 1), ('laborum', 1)]
```

And the second, `document_frequency_dict`: which is a dictionary showing the total amount of documents one term shows up in

```
{'sit': 1, 'amet': 1, 'dolor': 2, 'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'nostrud': 1, 'tempor': 1, 'exercitation': 1, 'magna': 1, 'elit': 1, 'ut': 1, 'ex':
1, 'ad': 1, 'consequat': 1, 'incididunt': 1, 'sed': 1, 'laboris': 1, 'veniam': 1, 'et': 1, 'quis': 1, 'dolore': 2, 'labore': 1, 'minim': 1, 'ullamco': 1, 'eiusmod': 1, 'commodo': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'ea': 1, 'aliquip': 1, 'enim': 1, 'nisi': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'aliqua': 1, 'voluptate': 1, 'reprehenderit': 1, 'eu': 1, 'aute': 1, 'cillum': 1, 'pariatur': 1, 'nulla': 1, 'duis': 1, 'velit': 1, 'fugiat': 1, 'irure': 1, 'esse': 1, 'proident': 1, 'sint': 1, 'officia': 1, 'sunt': 1, 'qui': 1, 'deserunt': 1, 'laborum': 1, 'excepteur': 1, 'anim': 1, 'cupidatat': 1, 'culpa': 1, 'id': 1, 'non': 1, 'mollit': 1, 'occaecat': 1, 'est': 1}
```

I need to combine these two items into one dictionary with the following shape:
`word: document_frequency, ((document_id, occurences in that document), (document_id, occurences in that document)), word: etc..`

It should be noted that `document_id` derives from the

tags in the input file, which will always exist. I am *assuming* they will always be in order, only because I cannot conceive of a solution when they are out of order.

Taking for example the word `dolor`...

`'dolor': 2, (1, 1), (2, 1)`

How can I accomplish the creation of this custom data structure?

The current code body is below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import csv
import operator
import re
import pandas
import collections
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import sys

def remove_nums(arr): 
    pattern = '[0-9]'
    arr = [re.sub(pattern, '', i) for i in arr] 
    return arr

# Main Program
def main():
    myfile = get_input("path")

    stop_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))
    p = r'<P ID=\d+>(.*?)</P>'
    paras = RegexpTokenizer(p)
    num_paragraphs = len(paras.tokenize(myfile))
    currFrequency = collections.Counter()
    #currFrequencies = []
    id_num = 1
    words = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

    document_frequency = collections.Counter()
    for para in paras.tokenize(myfile):
        lower = [word.lower() for word in words.tokenize(para)]
        no_integers = remove_nums(lower)
        dirty_tokens = [data for data in no_integers if data not in stop_words]
        tokens = [data for data in dirty_tokens if data.strip()]
        document_frequency.update(set(tokens))

    for para in paras.tokenize(myfile):
        lower = [word.lower() for word in words.tokenize(para)]
        no_integers = remove_nums(lower)
        dirty_tokens = [data for data in no_integers if data not in stop_words]
        tokens = [data for data in dirty_tokens if data.strip()]

        currFrequencies = collections.Counter(tokens)
        d = dict(currFrequencies)
        items = list(d.items())
        print(items)
        id_num += 1

    print()
    document_frequency_dict = dict(document_frequency)
    print(document_frequency_dict)
```

For reference, an example file is:

```
<P ID=1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</P>

<P ID=2>
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</P>

<P ID=3>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</P>

<P ID=4>
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</P>

<P ID=5>
654654
</P>
```

Comment: Where in your `items` and `document_frequency_dict` data are the "document IDs" supposed to come from? Also, instead of trying to combine `items` and `document_frequency_dict` in the way you describe, would it be satisfactory to just build this new output from the input directly?

Comment: Good question, I should have explained better. I will edit post. The "IDs" come from the <P ID=x></P> tags (in the example document, and in the regular expression tokenizer). And yes, I think building it from input directly is ideal, I am just about in tears because I cannot figure out how.

Comment: For the downvote / vote to close, can there be a question posed to me surrounding how it is too broad? I am asking how to merge two currently existing data structures into a `dict`? I do not see how this is broad.

Comment: It wasn't me, but "too broad" is a standard reply to homework questions. The idea is that the question isn't really "how do I fix my code?" but "how do I satisfy the instructor's specifications?", which could be done in all sorts of ways (at least, if they want to avoid the headaches when it comes to detecting plagiarism).

Comment: Sure, it is assignment related, but the assignment requirements aren't posted, this is _my_ interpretation of them and _my_ choice to create this data structure to satisfy. I would think that question is SO appropriate? I feel belittle. I appreciate your help immensely.

Comment: As an aside: `document_frequency.update(set(tokens))` is wrong. You are supposed to give the `tokens` directly to the Counter, so that it can actually *count* the duplicates. Building a `set` first guarantees that there are no duplicates, so the Counter will register at most one instance of a word per paragraph.

Comment: Is that true? Look at the word `dolor`, it shows the correct value of `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first, items, which is a list of a lists where each list counts the frequency of a term in a document

This is not actually the case; your code builds one of the intended inner lists each time through the loop, but does not put them into a list of lists. As seen here:

```
    d = dict(currFrequencies)
    items = list(d.items())
    print(items) # the list is printed, but not stored. It's overwritten each time.
    id_num += 1 # Nothing in the code actually uses this value!
```

In fact, the existing `currFrequencies` is a much more appropriate data structure for the next step, because it lets us directly answer the question, "given the histogram for a specific document, and a word, how many times does the word appear?".

You should try to build a dict of these `collections.Counter` instances, mapping from the ID key (you can read this from the original HTML as well) to the Counter. Once you have that, the next step is to get the pairs of (id, count) values, something like:

```
def counts_in_each_paragraph(per_paragraph_counts, word):
    return [
        # the id and the looked-up frequency
        (id, counter[word])
        # of each per-paragraph Counter
        for id, counter in per_paragraph_counts.items()
        # that contains a (non-zero) count for the word
        if word in counter
    ]
```

which you can then build into the final result, something like:

```
def full_histogram(per_paragraph_counts, overall_counts):
    return {
        # map the word to its overall count plus per-paragraph count pairs
        word: (count, (counts_in_each_paragraph(per_paragraph_counts, word))
        # across all of the overall-count data
        for word, count in overall_counts.items()
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I am seeming dumb, I am trying to understand. `counts_in_each_paragraph`, where does id come from? We are passing in `per_paragraph_counts` and `word`, is that the `key...value` pair currently held in `collectionFrequency` for a single id? what is `counter`? I guess I'm getting confused as to what is supposed to be happening in this function.

Comment: `where does id come from?` `per_paragraph_counts` needs to become a dictionary, specifically the one described in the previous paragraph; then the .items() of that dict are key-value pairs, with `id` as the key (paragraph ID) and `counter` the Counter instance (histogram of that paragraph). These aren't the names used in your code, because you'd have to do the work I hinted at anyway; I can't do *everything* for you.

Comment: `histogram of that paragraph`, is that definition supposed to be the output of `('lorem', 1), ('ipsum', 1), ('dolor', 1), ('sit', 1), ('amet', 1)` for `P ID=1` for example? I ask because that is what I am using, following the above logic, for odd results ;-)